# Is it possible to alter innerHTML/textContent back and forth (endlessly)?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, addeventlistener

So i'm thinking to changing innerHTML of `<p>Click</p>` from content of "Click" into "Clicked" and when being clicked again it changes back again to "Click" (and could be clicked back again to result "Clicked" for endless times).

Can someone give clue? *I appreciate,

This is my fail attempt so far -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<p id="event_01">Click</p>

<script>
    let goo = document.querySelector("#event_01");

    let clickOnce = function() {goo.innerHTML = "Clicked"};

    let clickBack = function(){
    goo.innerHTML = "Click"};

    if(goo.textContent == "Click") {
        goo.addEventListener("click", clickOnce);
    } else if (goo.textContent == "Clicked") {
        goo.addEventListener("click", clickBack);
    }

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: thank Mr Mohammedreza Farahani for editing some mistake on my code. ;) appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your condition inside a click handler instead of outside. What's between the script tag will only execute once. When the code runs (on page load) the content of goo is Click, so only the listener that sets the content to "clicked" ever gets attached to the element. instead you should do somthing like this:

```
let goo = document.querySelector("#event_01");

let onClick = function() {
    if(goo.textContent == "Click"){
        goo.innerHTML = "Clicked";     
    } else {
        goo.innerHTML = "Click";
    }
};


goo.addEventListener("click", clickOnce);
```

Comment: thank you Sir. It seems that it is just a very easy question  for everyone. ;) thanks again @Alen.Toma

Comment: Probably only "easy" if you happen to be an experienced frontend engineer :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the value of the `.innerHTML` of the `<p></p>`, compare it to the current .innerHTML and change it accordingly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <body>
       <p id="event_01" onClick="myFunction()">Click</p>
       <script>

           function myFunction() {
               var x = document.getElementById("event_01");
               if (x.innerHTML === "Click") {
                    x.innerHTML = "Clicked";
               } else {
                    x.innerHTML = "Click";
               }
           }

       </script>
       </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one listener, attached from the beginning:

```
let goo = document.querySelector("#event_01");
goo.addEventListener("click", clickListener);

let clickListener = function() {
    if (goo.innerHTML == "<p>Click</p>")
        goo.innerHTML = "<p>Clicked</p>";
    else
        goo.innerHTML = "<p>Click</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. your adding to much code.
first of when the p is clicked you assign a click event to clickOnce but in clickOnce 
back you never assign clickBack.

Here is an example about what you want to do.

```js
       let goo = document.querySelector("#event_01");

       let clickMe = function() { 
       if(goo.textContent == "Click")
       {
         goo.innerHTML = "Clicked";
       }
       else
       {
         goo.innerHTML = "Click";
       }
       
       }


    
     goo.addEventListener("click", clickMe);
```

```html
       <p id="event_01">Click</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use functions or variables, you can use `e.target.textContent`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<body>
    <p id="event_01">Click</p>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("#event_01").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if (e.target.textContent === 'Click') {
                e.target.textContent = 'Clicked'
            } else if (e.target.textContent === 'Clicked') {
                e.target.textContent = 'Click'
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```